# How to get the snapshot.error in Flutter 2?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I updated my Flutter app to Flutter 2, and now when I try to get the snapshot.error in my StreamBuider I get this [image]

These are validators with Streams.

```
class LoginStreams with Validators {

  dispose() {
    _emailController.close();
    _passwordController.close();
  }

  Function(String) get emailOnChange => _emailController.sink.add;
  Function(String) get passwordOnChange => _passwordController.sink.add;

  final _emailController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();
  final _passwordController = StreamController<String>.broadcast();

  Stream<String> get emailStream => 
    _emailController.stream.transform(emailValidator);
  Stream<String> get passwordStream =>       
 _passwordController.stream.transform(passwordValidator);

}
```

--

```
class Validators {
  final passwordValidator = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
      handleData: (password, sink) {
    password.length >= 5
        ? sink.add(password)
        : sink.addError("La contraseña debe contener más de 5 caracteres");
  });

  final emailValidator =
      StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(handleData: (email, sink) {
    if (email.contains('@') && email.contains('.')) {
      sink.add(email);
    } else {
      sink.addError("Ingrese un email válido");
    }
  });
}
```

---

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: _validators.emailStream,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)=>TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            controller: emailController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              errorText: '$snapshot.error',
              labelText: widget.loginModel.emailTextfield,
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(CmbSpacing.SpaceMD))),
            onChanged: _validators.emailOnChange,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: CmbSpacing.SpaceSM),
          StreamBuilder(
            stream: _validators.passwordStream,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)=>TextField(
            controller: passwordController,
            obscureText: true,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              errorText: '$snapshot.error',
              suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.visibility_off_outlined),
              labelText: widget.loginModel.passwordTextfield,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(CmbSpacing.SpaceMD))),
            onChanged: _validators.passwordOnChange,
            ),
          ),
```

If someone could help me i would be so gratefull, I am so confused because after upgrading to Flutter 2 this used to work great.

It's something new about StreamBuilders in Flutter 2?

EDIT:

I changed "$snapshot.error" to snapshot.error.toString()

and now I get null.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not interpolating the error correctly.
If you want to call an extra method before interpolating, you have to wrap the expression in `${}`, e.g. `'${snapshot.error}`. In your case you're just appending `.error` to a string representation of `snapshot`

Replace

```dart
errorText: '$snapshot.error'
```

With

```dart
errorText: snapshot.error?.toString()

// or if you want to use it in a sentence
errorText: "This is the error: ${snapshot.error}"
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to apply condition statement overthere:

```
errorText: snapshot.hasError ? '${snapshot.error}' : null
```

I'm sure this will help. :)